# Selenium Scroll Element in list (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to Scroll down in a list up to certain elements. But It's not working for me.

Trying Following Code.

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",elementToScroll);
```

Here is the image, in **Organization Setup** below **Email Templates** there are certain elements available. So I want to click me. But until they don't appear on the screen I cant click.
Can someone help me to tackle the issue?
[image]

Comment: Share the HTML please

Comment: Are you able to find it but you can't click it?

Comment: Yes,I am able to find it but not click it.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/alA9pm

Comment: @JayVyas Have you tried the moveToElement method of the actions class. It will scroll to the element which is inbuilt in it. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-

Comment: Show us the element  `elementToScroll` please.

Comment: @DebanjanB
I have shared the code

Comment: @Grasshopper
I have tried moveToElement,But still facing same issue.
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
   actions.moveToElement(element);
   actions.perform();

Comment: @Jay Vyas, in some case the page rely on the velocity of the scroll which needs to be simulated: [`arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end"});`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579690/ionic-3-infinite-scroll-simulate-in-e2e-test-jasmine-protractor/47580259#47580259)

Comment: @FlorentB.
Not working bro

Comment: @Jay Vyas, it could be that you are not locating the correct element. It's not possible to say why it's not working without a reproducible example.

Comment: @Jay Vyas, try with some sleep to see if it's due to an animation.

Comment: and exactly why can't you click said element to drop down, then do a search of the page for "me" and if it's not there scroll again, search "me", if not found, scroll again, until "me" is found?  I do this kind of thing for paging, it is possible if done right.

Answer (score 0):

I have a method to view any element into middle of the screen. The method is

```
public void viewElementToCenter(WebElement ele){

    String scrollElementIntoMiddle = "var viewPortHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);"
            + "var elementTop = arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;"
            + "window.scrollBy(0, elementTop-(viewPortHeight/2));";

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(scrollElementIntoMiddle, ele);
    //((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

call this method like below

```
viewElementToCenter(elementToScroll);
```

Then click on that element as

```
elementToScroll.click();
```

Comment: Not Working dude

Comment: @JayVyas as a workaround please try to view a element to center that is on the screens lower part. Do this part untill your element is on the center.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this one and Get your Luck:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)", "");
```

(0,500) : **Increase Pixel Size to scroll more downward, along the x-axis (horizontal).**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code..

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.evaluate(xpathofelement_toclick, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotItem(0).scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();");
```